# CORS error with Facebook callback function

Tags: angularjs, node.js, facebook, cors, passport.js

I have the following code:

app.js:

```js
var passport = require('passport')
  , FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy
  , ...
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log('serializing user')
  done(null, user);
})
passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  console.log('deserializeUser')
  done(null, obj)
})
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FBAPP.id,
    clientSecret: FBAPP.secret,
    callbackURL: 
      "http://www.mylocal.com:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {
      return done(null, profile)
    })
  }
))
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', 
  { scope: ['email, user_likes, user_photos, publish_actions'] }))
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', 
passport.authenticate('facebook', { 
  successRedirect: '/loginsuccess', failureRedirect : '/loginfail' }))
app.get('loginsuccess', function(req, res) {
   console.log('Login success')
  res.send(200, 'ok')
})
app.get('/loginfail', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Login error')
  res.send(401, 'error')
})
```

The angular part:

```js
factory('FacebookFactory', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    var get = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({method: 'GET', url: '/auth/facebook'}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
    return {
        get: get
    };
}])
```

I get always this error and did several attempts but no success.

```js
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%…
user_likes%2C%20user_photos%2C%20publish_actions&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxx. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header 
is present on the requested resource. Origin '[basic
links]http://www.mylocal.com:3000' is therefore 
not allowed access.
```

Anyone any idea? I did try it solely in angular but then it does not work in Safari but in Chrome and FF it works perfectly.

www.mylocal.com:3000 = localhost:3000

Comment: same problem here! did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: In fact no. Besides restart from scratch with a new app on the Facebook side. It worked but the comparison did not show any difference.

Comment: Do you perhaps need to use $http.jsonp()? Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

You will not find a solution with client side languages as this constitutes a cross-origin request which could be used as a malicious attack. So basically the Facebook endpoint would need to have a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header block set and I don't think they will do that anytime soon. I use APIs alot and frequently have to have theses headers set in my endpoint so my clients can connect from localhost or dev urls:

```
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])):
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
    endif;
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS'):
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'])):
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT');
        endif;
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS'])):
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
        endif;
        exit(0);
    endif;
```

You could also try this in your $http broker:

```
        var promise = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'url_to_api',
            data: params,
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            return data;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an Angular app with express on the backend. When I clicked on a button with this HTML:

```
<input type="button" ng-click="socialLogIn('facebook')" class="modal-input" value="Sign in with Facebook">
```

It gave me a CORS error:

```
$scope.socialLogIn = function (social) {
    return $http.get ('/auth/'+social).success (function (data) {
        auth.saveToken (data.token);  // write data to local storage
    });
```

Problem is, I wanted to get the token back so I could save it in localStorage. I did solve it, but the solution is round-about. In the socialLogIn function, I opened a new window:

```
$scope.socialLogIn = function (social) {
    var url = 'http://' + $window.location.host + '/auth/' + social;
    $window.open(url);
};
```

In the express backend, after I got my 'stuff' from Facebook or Google and I created the token, I sent back some code that saved the token, reloaded the parent window and closed itself:

```
function loginReturn (res, token) {
  var returnString = '' +
          '<!DOCTYPE html>\n' +
          '<html>\n' +
            '<head>\n' +
              '<meta charset="UTF-8">\n' +
              '<title>Login</title>\n' +
            '</head>\n' +
            '<body>\n' +
            '<script type="text/javascript">\n' +
              'window.localStorage[\'token\']  = \''+token+'\';\n' +
              'window.opener.location.reload(false);\n' +
              'window.close();\n' +
            '</script>\n' +
            '</body>\n' +
          '</html>'; 

  res.send(returnString);
};
```